# general guidelines on what is done to setup user accounts on a debian/linux server

Tags: linux

Ok to get things in perspective (whatever you can say on the subject the better, or links to lead me into more detailed subject matter etc).

Say you have a dedicated box, security is all setup etc. (firewall etc., not user account security...for arguments sake).

Now you are setting up this server to provide hosting, **and you are doing this 'manually' without the aid of a control panel.**

Requirements:
1. you need to create user folders so they have a place to store their information.
2. setup quotas on each user folder

So users will use these folders to upload their static content (html files say, or use it as a place to store files).

**How would you go about doing this?** And how would you automatic the process?

1. where would you store your automation scripts
2. where would you create each users folder?
3. how would you block things from being executed in their folder?

Answer (score 2):

1. `/usr/local/sbin/adduser.local` (as per `adduser`(8))
2. `/home`
3. You can't.

Comment: if you have home directories on another partition and use the noexec mount option you add some sort of protection

Comment: noexec is useless.  There are so many ways to get around it's "protection", it's not worth worrying about.